# How to replace a sentence with space on the basis of a pattern if it occurs in the middle of a sentence

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

Suppose I have a line like this:

```
aaaa ---- bbbb
```

I want to erase the `----bbbb` part, but I want to keep the `aaaa` part as it is in the file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed:

```
s='aaaa ---- bbbb'
echo "$s"|sed 's/--* bb*/foo/'
aaaa foo
```

Comment: @anubhava..Suppose these are some lines in a file for which I need the above functionality then need to transform the same in a difference file without the bbb part. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Thanks for the cue. :). To generalise the functionality I used this echo "$s"|sed 's/--* [a-z A-Z0-9 0-9 ^0-9 ]*$//' and it was working fine. :). Cheers